# Trim String while preserving line breaks

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, removing-whitespace

The `trim()` method for **String** returns a string having leading and trailing whitespace removed, which also includes line breaks (`'\n'`). How we can get `trim()` functionality while keeping line breaks ?

For example: `"\n   this is new line   "` -> `"\nthis is new line"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replaceAll instead

**edit**

```
    String str = "\n     this is new line    ";
    str = str.replaceAll("\n\\s+", "\n").replaceAll("\\s+$", "");

    System.out.println(str);
```

**output**

this is new line

Comment: Thx for quick reply, it's would be good to handle case where we can have multiple white space after line break.

Comment: I think it doesn't work, let me double check. I am using kotlin and using `replace` instead `replaceAll`.

Comment: If you need to use replace, then use `"\n "` and keep doing until size of String does not change

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to find equivalent to `replaceAll` in `kotlin`.

Comment: @Levon I _think_ you want https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html, specifically `CharSequence#replace(Regex,String)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main() {
  var str = "\n     this is new line    "
  str = str
    .replace("\n\\s+".toRegex(), "\n")
    .replace("\\s+$".toRegex(), "")
  println(str)
}
```

I think, that is what you want